# How to bond weather seal to concrete floor under garage door

Tags: concrete, adhesive, weatherstripping

I have one of those generic Garage Door Weather Seal rubber strips that go under my canopy door. It came with an adhesive to bond it with, but I've noticed that it's started to lift in a lot of places. The adhesive is still stuck to the seal, so I will need a new seal to start again.

How can I prime the raw concrete floor to better bond with the adhesive? Is there a certain type of adhesive I need to use?

Comment: Please post a picture

Comment: Is a "generic Garage Door Weather Seal" something that's supposed to attach to the bottom of your garage door, or to the ground? What's a "canopy door"? Your terms are perfectly obvious to you, but a little lost on us without any pictures...

Comment: Please [Edit] your question and use the 'sun & mountains' button to add one or more pics of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Before installing the next one, clean, clean again, clean some more, and dry the surface really well.

The supplied adhesive should be intended for the job, but can't be expected to work well if there's oil, grease or dirt between it and the actual concrete.

Comment: Thanks - there's definitely no oil, grease, or dirt.. it was fresh concrete when I first applied it! I can only think it's to do with the concrete being slightly dusty. Would I be better off applying PVA to the concrete first?

Comment: How fresh? Most things should not be applied to concrete less than 30 days old.